# State changes after 2 clicks and useEffect also not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have a basic template of a react website with a button that connects to your metamask wallet and displays the current balance.

I have the classic issue that the state of 'addressBalance' only becomes visible after the second click on the connect wallet button. (Basically: I need to click 2 times to show the changes of the 'addressBalance' state.)

I added a useEffect hook that gets triggered whenever 'addressBalance' state changes however the useEffect also only gets triggered on loading the page & after the second click.

This is my code:

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

function App() {
  const [walletAddress, setWalletAddress] = useState("");
  const [addressBalance, setaddressBalance] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Balance updated:", addressBalance);
  }, [addressBalance]);

  async function requestAccount() {
    console.log("Requesting account...");

    if (window.ethereum) {
      console.log("detected");

      try {
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
        });

        setWalletAddress(accounts[0]);
        getBalance();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error connecting...");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Meta Mask not detected");
    }
  }

  function getBalance() {
    const result = window.ethereum
      .request({
        method: "eth_getBalance",
        params: [walletAddress, "latest"],
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        let wei = parseInt(result, 16);
        let balance = wei / 10 ** 18;
        setaddressBalance(balance);
      });
  }

  async function connectWallet() {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
      await requestAccount();

      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <button className="request-account" onClick={requestAccount}>
          Request Account
        </button>
        <h3>Wallet Address: {walletAddress}</h3>
        <h3>
          {!walletAddress
            ? "No address connected..."
            : `Balance: ${addressBalance} ETH`}
        </h3>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'd like to know how it is possible that the useEffect hook isn't triggered after the first click and how I can fix this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: `walletAddress` in `getBalance` has an old value, because `setWalletAddress(accounts[0]);` doesn't change the value in the same render cycle. The new value will be available when the component rerenders. Easy fix: Add a param to the `getBalance(address)` and call it with `getBalance(accounts[0])`

Comment: @Konrad Thanks for your answer! How can I make sure that the component re-renders before calling getBalance? If I understand you correctly that would fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` hook isn't getting triggered on the first click because when you call `setWalletAddress`, your `getBalance` function immediately tries to access the value of `walletAddress` but because of React's "asynchronous" state update behavior, the `walletAddress` variable hasn't been updated to `accounts[0]` by the time you've called `getBalance()`.

An easy way to fix this is to pass the wallet address as an explicit parameter to `getBalance`:

```
 async function requestAccount() {
    console.log("Requesting account...");

    if (window.ethereum) {
      console.log("detected");

      try {
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
        });

        setWalletAddress(accounts[0]);
        getBalance(accounts[0]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error connecting...");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Meta Mask not detected");
    }
  }

  function getBalance(walletAddress) {
    const result = window.ethereum
      .request({
        method: "eth_getBalance",
        params: [walletAddress, "latest"],
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        let wei = parseInt(result, 16);
        let balance = wei / 10 ** 18;
        setaddressBalance(balance);
      });
  }
```

Comment: +1 , this works! So instead of getting the walletAdress from state you pass it on to the getBalance function. How couldn't I think of this !